# ipython and pydev, tab-completion

Tags: eclipse, pydev, ipython

I followed this guide http://pydev.blogspot.com/2011/08/ipython-pydev.html to setup Ipython with pydev

But how do I enable tab-completion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The integration works with Ctrl+Space for code-completion purposes (and not tab as would be the default in IPython).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to enable the option: 
Window->Preferences->PyDev->Code Completion->"Request Completion on all letter chars and '_'?"